# Adding new tabs in ionic framework

Tags: layout, ionic-framework, tabs, mobile-development

I want to use a tab layout in my ionic framework, so I started making it. By default it provides me 3 tabs, but now I want to add more tabs to it.

I did it by making changes in the tabs folder and "tab.html" file. Now I want to do coding of the new tab pages which I just added in "tabs.html". So for this I created new folders of the new tabs inside the pages folder. Now I want to code the new tabs I have added.

My question is how to do this. I tried by making new html file inside the folder of that page. But that gave me an error..

Please suggest me the solution as I am very new to ionic framework.

Comment: What was the error message? Also, can you show some code (to better see what you tried)?

Comment: <ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="More" tabIcon="more"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Menu" tabIcon="menu"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Files" tabIcon="folder-open"></ion-tab>

  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Account" 
tabIcon="settings"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Purchase" 
tabIcon="cart"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

Comment: above is the code of my tabs.html file.Now when i want to add new folder for the  new tabs,how should i do that??and what is the meaning of <ion-tab[root]="tab3root"...>

Comment: That tag controls the root template for that tab. Basically, you would create new tab roots and name them whatever you want, then put those names in the `<ion-tab[root]=` part. I will write an answer to better explain it.

Comment: Thanks i will try this.

Comment: @vithika Try this https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#slides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tab/), the way to create a new tab is:

1) Adding the `<ion-tab>` tag to the HTML. For example:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Tab 1"></ion-tab>
  //...
  <ion-tab [root]="myTabRoot" tabTitle="myTitle"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

2) Create the new root page like you would any new page. For example:

```
export class myRootPage {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

3) Assign the root page attribute to the root page itself inside the Tabs module. For example:

```
export class Tabs {
  myTabRoot = myRootPage;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Note that you will need to import your tab root page into the Tabs module (using the `import{}` command).
As for how you create a new page, I assume you already know all the steps - if you don't, there are many tutorials online that should help you.

Comment: Where do i need to code for the second step,which file?                                              export class myRootPage { 
  constructor() {
  }
}

Comment: You need to create a new TypeScript (.ts) file. Using the myRootPage as an example, you'd create a "my-root-page.ts" file and then you'd put the myRootPage code inside it.

Of course, you also need to import the proper Ionic and Angular components for it to work - if you want to, you can copy one of the existing files for the other tab's root pages and just modify its title (and contents). It's easier than creating a page from nothing.

Comment: I am able to create new tabs  .thanks a lot.it solved my problem

Comment: No problem! Be sure to approve my answer later!

Comment: Yeah i dont have much reputation now,but i have already upvoted it .Thank you  so much.

Answer (score 1):

I referred to ionicframwork.docs//intro/tutorial/project-structure/ 
This tutorial fully explain the ionic structure and is very helpful to the beginner like me.
It explains how to add new tabs to your app.